# How can i find object from an array in mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have a schema like following : -

```
var P = {
     s : [{
         data : [],
         sec : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
     }]
 };
```

Now I want to find only the object of section not entire the row. Like If I pass `sec` value I want only the value of `s.data` of that `sec` object.

example : -

```
{ s : [ 
    {
       data : [],
       sec : '52b9830cadaa9d273200000d'
    },{
        data : [],
       sec : '52b9830cadaa9d2732000005'
    }
  ]
}
```

Result should be look like -

```
 {
    data : [],
    sec : '52b9830cadaa9d2732000005'
 }
```

I do not want all entire row. Is it possible? If yes, then please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `$elemMatch` projection operator to limit an array field like `s` to a single, matched element, but you can't remove the `s` level of your document using `find`.

```
db.test.find({}, {_id: 0, s: {$elemMatch: {sec: '52b9830cadaa9d2732000005'}}})
```

outputs:

```
{
  "s": [
    {
      "data": [ ],
      "sec": "52b9830cadaa9d2732000005"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the value of some field by using find(). For example in your case:

```
db.collectionName.find({},{s.data:1})
```

So the first bracket is to apply any condition or query, and in the second bracket you have to  define the field as 1(to fetch only those fields value).

Please check http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find for more information.
Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer give me the whole array. But I want only the particular object of the array. If you have any suggestion reply me.

Answer (score 0):

Not into Mongo or db but working with **Pure JavaSript skills** here is the Solution as you mentioned **Node.js** which would do the execution task of the below.

**Schema**

```
   var P = { s : [ 
            {
             data : [],
             sec : '52b9830cadaa9d273200000d'
              },{
             data : [],
             sec : '52b9830cadaa9d2732000005'
              }
         ]
    };
```

**Search Method Code**

```
var search = function (search_sec){
     for (var i=0; i<(P.s.length);i++){

       var pointer = P.s[i].sec;
       var dataRow = P.s[i];

        if((pointer) === search_sec ){

             console.log(dataRow);

          }
      }

};
```

Here is How you can call - **search('search_id');**

For example input : 
**search('52b9830cadaa9d2732000005');**

**Output:**

```
 [object Object] {
                  data: [],
                  sec: "52b9830cadaa9d2732000005"
                  }
```

Working Demo here - http://jsbin.com/UcobuVOf/1/watch?js,console